# Is there a way to control kubectl exec through something like rbac or anything else?

Tags: ssh, kubernetes, rbac

I want to know if I can limit access to developers, we want to only allow developers to list pods and check logs, no ssh into pods, is that feasible ? This is what I tried, but it seems to not work ..

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: developer-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods", "pods/log"]
    verbs: ["get", "list"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/exec"]
    verbs: [""]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: developer-role
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: developer-role
subjects:
  - kind: Group
    name: developer_customized
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty set of verbs for the resource pods/exec does not grant any access, but also does not deny it. It would depend on other configurations.

To effectively deny access, you should remove the lines for pods/exec

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: developer-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods", "pods/log"]
    verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I did that, and it is not working, is it possible that another cluster rolebinding is interfering ? and in that case do you know how do I find the culprit ? though, I only have binded just 1 cluster role to my group.

Comment: There are some commands you can try: "kubectl get role bindings,customrolebindings --all-namespaces -o yaml" will list those resources and you can review "subjects". There is also the command "kubectl auth can-i create pods --as=<username>". Same thing with list_pods

Answer (score 0):

Base on your YAML file, you may want to try to add a verb get for pod/exec:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: developer-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods", "pods/log"]
    verbs: ["get", "list"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/exec"]
    verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: developer-role
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: developer-role
subjects:
  - kind: Group
    name: developer_customized
```

If it doesn't work, make sure the group membership is correct and doesn't have any conflicting `ClusterRole`. You can use command `kubectl get events` for gain more info about your cluster.